# "Didn't” or “Wouldn't" in this context?

Tags: conditional-constructions

I have just watched a scene from a show where they said this:

> Person 1: Imagine you were home alone, feeling sick, what would you do?
>
> Person 2: I would call my mom.
>
> Person1 : And if she **didn't** answer?

Could **didn't**  be replaced with **wouldn't** in this context? If it could, would there be any difference in meaning?

To my mind, by putting *did not* we express she did not have the ability to answer. In case of *would not*, it indicates she kept calling again and again and she would not answer. (Though I am no native speaker, so who knows.)

Answer (score 1):

"Didn't" cannot be replaced by "wouldn't" without changing the meaning. "Did not answer" simply means that the phone rang and rang and was not picked up. That's all. It says nothing about the mother's ability to answer, simply that the phone was not answered. "Would not answer" is different, It says that the mother heard the phone and refused to answer, even though she could. In any case, using "would not" is unlikely. How would the caller know that the mother was refusing to answer?

Comment: Are you sure that only means this: "... simply means that the phone rang and rang and was not picked up"? Couldn't it mean that she didn't answer for whatever reason? I mean she might feel down and frustrated from life and she didn't answer the call though hearing the ring!

Comment: Cardinal, not in that conversation.

Answer (score 0):

"And if she **wouldn't** answer?" is grammatical, but it has a different meaning and it is not likely something we would ever say.

> by putting did not we express she did not have the ability to answer.

This is not correct.  "She did not answer" actually gives no indication about why or how she didn't answer. It is the simplest and most neutral way of describing that an action did not take place. The idea you suggested would be expressed by "she **couldn't** answer."

"She **wouldn't** answer" here implies some idea like *in every case, no matter what, she would not answer*, or perhaps it describes some habitual action: *every time he called, she would not answer*. It's hard to say exactly what it would mean, since it's not something we would say.